# How can update field by overriding save method which is in another app models

Tags: django-models, sql-update, overriding, django-queryset, drf-queryset

I have two models **Bill** and **Payment** each with 3 fields.  Here I want to update field last_price directly when user pay bill. If user pay complete amount then it would be 0. or if user not pay complete amount then **remaining amount want to be save in last_price**. So here I want to update amount of last_bill directly when user pay bill.

**Note: Both models are in separate app**

**My Fields are:**

**BillApp/models**

```
 Bill(model.Model):
      bill_no = models.IntegerField(max_length = 100,primary_key=True)
      last_price = models.IntegerField()
      Name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

**PaymentApp/models**

```
Payment(model.Model):
  id = models.CharField(max_length = 100,primary_key=True)
  bill_no = models.ForeignKey(Bill, on_delete = SET_NULL,null=True)
  total_amount = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
  
def save(...):
       Update value of Bill.last_price
```

How do I **update value of Bill.last_price** in the save method

**I tried this for update field last_price**

```
 def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
     new_last_price =  self.total_amount -  self.bill_no.last_price
     print("new_last_price : ",new_last_price)
     bill_detail = Bill.objects.filter(bill_no=self.bill_no).first()
     print("bill_detail : ",bill_detail)

     try:
         with transaction.atomic():
         updated_field = bill_detail.save(update_fields = ['last_price'])
         print("updated_field : ", updated_field)
         super().save(*args, **kwargs)
         print(Bill.objects.filter(bill_no=self.bill_no).first().last_price)
     except IntegrityError:
         print('Exception in save')
```

I **getting correct output of new_last_price and bill_detail..**
but **updated_field display None ..**
How Can I save new value in Bill?

Answer (score 0):

Your save method will save the data and refresh the object instance but will not return the object instance. Use directly show last price.

```
bill_detail.save(update_fields = ['last_price'])
print(bill_detail.last_price)
```